# Simple Absolute Value Proof

Tags: proof-writing

> Let $\circ$  be an inequality.
>
> Prove  $|x| \circ a \equiv -a \circ x \circ a$.

If $x$ is positive, then $|x| \circ a = x \circ a$.

If $x$ is negative, then $|x| \circ a = x \circ a$ ?

Comment: Very strange ! What is the meaning of " let $ \circ$ be an inequality " ????

Comment: If $\circ$ is choosen to be $>$, then this makes no sense. $-a>x>a$ is not the same as $|x|>a$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have to show:  for $x,a \in \mathbb R$ and $a \ge 0$:

$|x| \le a$ implies  $-a \le x \le a$.

Case 1: $x \ge 0$. Then we get from $|x| \le a$ that $0 \le x \le a$ and hence $-a \le x \le a$.

Case 2: $x < 0$. Then we get from $|x| \le a$ that $- x \le a$ and hence $-a \le x <0$, thus $-a \le x \le a$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $\circ$ can be either $<$ or $>$.

If $x>0$, then $|x|\circ a \equiv x\circ a$.

If $x<0$, then $ |x|\circ a \equiv -x\circ a$.